# How to find Stored Procedures execution time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 10 stored procedures as follows:
SP1,SP2,.....,SP10
These stored procedures do some stuff.
I need to run these procedures as follows:
EXECUTE SP1;
EXECUTE SP2;
...
EXECUTE SP10;

When SQL server finshes to complete execution of these procedures, it gives ten lines showing any row changes caused by all these stored procedures. 
**What i want to do is that after Execution of all stored procedures SQL Server also gives in output window the execution time for each Stored Procedures.**
Can i do this? I am sure that for achieving this task i need to modify stored procedures but i don't have any idea how to do it...
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Sql Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) for this purposes it provides a lot of useful info along the each executed query and Stored procedure as well.

[MSDN: SQL Profiler Data Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173882%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> SQL Profiler displays the execution time for each event

An other straightforward way:

1. DECLARE 2 datetime variables: start/end
2. SET start = GETDATE()
3. EXEC SP_NAME
4. SET end = GETDATE()
5. Execution time - difference between end and start

Comment: The Data Column Description link now points to "SQL Server 2000 Retired Technical documentation".  The first link (to Sql Server Profiler) still works.  I don't have permission to edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the difference between two dates by using: `datediff(millisecond, @start, @end)`

Answer (score 33):

Assuming management studio or some other environment with an output pane you can;

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
EXEC SP1
EXEC SP2
...
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

Answer (score 10):

```
declare @start datetime = getdate()

-- your SQL statements
exec dbo.MyStoredProcedure

declare @executionTimeInMilliseconds int = datediff(ms, @start, getdate())
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to modify the SPs code at all. The following query gives you some stats about SPs execution times.

```
SELECT 
   DB_NAME(database_id) [database],
   OBJECT_NAME(object_id) [stored_procedure],
   cached_time, 
   last_execution_time, 
   execution_count,
   total_elapsed_time/execution_count [avg_elapsed_time],
   [type_desc]
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
--WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) IN ('SP1','SP2','SP3','SP4','SP5')
ORDER BY avg_elapsed_time desc;
```

Just try it.

Comment: I like this answer because I can see the values After the fact.   We have nightly data-compiles and I am analyzing where all of the time is being spent... and these are Hours long jobs.  The SET STATS TIME suggestions require me to sit and wait,  plus they don't output the names of any child sp calls.

Comment: PS - I added cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan (s.plan_handle)  and can now get the query-plan.   Also note that the elapsed time includes time spent in the call to children sps.  e.g. is main calls child1 and child2,  and child1 take 30 and child2 takes 60,  main will be (at least) 90.

Answer (score 5):

There are ways to do this using tools such as Sql Server profiler, but a simple way is to run each proc surrounded with a line to print the time:

```
print convert(varchar, getdate(), 21)
EXEC PROC SP1
print convert(varchar, getdate(), 21)
```

Comment: why would you convert to varchar ??? Basically what you should do is take the millisecond difference from before and after running the procedure

Comment: Simply so you can get a formatted output such as `2011-10-14 12:32:39.403`. Leaving it as datetime won't necessarily give you the milliseconds, and reporting _only_ the difference loses the extra data of **when** it was run, in case it's unattended.

Answer (score 1):

[capture and display execution time](http://4rapiddev.com/sql-server/capture-and-display-execution-time-of-sql-query-in-sql-server/)

use two parameter of `datetime` type 
and set one using `getdate()` before start of `tsql` in stored procedure

and set second using `getdate()` after `tsql` and finally use `datediff` function to get the difference